# How to convert list of multiple jsons into individual jsons using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list of jsons as mentioned below

```
    [
    {
        "files": 0, 
        "data": [
            {"name": "RFC", "value": "XXXXXXX", "attId": 01}, 
            {"name": "NOMBRE", "value": "JOSE", "attId": 02}, 
            {"name": "APELLIDO PATERNO", "value": "MONTIEL", "attId": 03}, 
            {"name": "APELLIDO MATERNO", "value": "MENDOZA", "attId": 04}, 
            {"name": "FECHA NACIMIENTO", "value": "1989-02-04", "attId": 05}
        ], 
        "dirId": 1, 
        "docId": 4, 
        "structure": {
            "name": "personales", 
            "folioId": 22
        }
    }, 
    {
        "files": 0, 
        "data": [
            {"name": "CALLE", "value": "AMOR", "attId": 06}, 
            {"name": "No. EXTERIOR", "value": "4", "attId": 07}, 
            {"name": "No. INTERIOR", "value": "2", "attId": 08}, 
            {"name": "C.P.", "value": "55060", "attId": 09}, 
            {"name": "ENTIDAD", "value": "ESTADO DE MEXICO", "attId": 10}, 
            {"name": "MUNICIPIO", "value": "ECATEPEC", "attId": 11}, 
            {"name": "COLONIA", "value": "INDUSTRIAL", "attId": 12}
            ], 
        "dirId": 1, 
        "docId": 4, 
        "structure": {
            "name": "direccion", 
            "folioId": 22
        }
    }
  ]
```

I need to convert this list of jsons into separate individual jsons and execute them separately.

how to achieve this using pyspark or python?

Comment: Can you try iterating the list then each item will be json file...

Comment: @sachin how to iterate the list of jsons

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, just one loop should work;

PN: There are few leading zeros in your input raw data...

```
# Assuming given list in your question is stored in lst
for item in lst:
    print(item,"\n")
    # item here will behave as individual dict/json
    # Do your coding here as required

# Output for items;
```

{'files': 0, 'data': [{'name': 'RFC', 'value': 'XXXXXXX', 'attId': '01'}, {'name': 'NOMBRE', 'value': 'JOSE', 'attId': '02'}, {'name': 'APELLIDO PATERNO', 'value': 'MONTIEL', 'attId': '03'}, {'name': 'APELLIDO MATERNO', 'value': 'MENDOZA', 'attId': '04'}, {'name': 'FECHA NACIMIENTO', 'value': '1989-02-04', 'attId': '05'}], 'dirId': 1, 'docId': 4, 'structure': {'name': 'personales', 'folioId': 22}}

{'files': 0, 'data': [{'name': 'CALLE', 'value': 'AMOR', 'attId': '06'}, {'name': 'No. EXTERIOR', 'value': '4', 'attId': '07'}, {'name': 'No. INTERIOR', 'value': '2', 'attId': '08'}, {'name': 'C.P.', 'value': '55060', 'attId': '09'}, {'name': 'ENTIDAD', 'value': 'ESTADO DE MEXICO', 'attId': '10'}, {'name': 'MUNICIPIO', 'value': 'ECATEPEC', 'attId': '11'}, {'name': 'COLONIA', 'value': 'INDUSTRIAL', 'attId': '12'}], 'dirId': 1, 'docId': 4, 'structure': {'name': 'direccion', 'folioId': 22}}